# Output of the following program that uses dynamic scoping

Tags: c, dynamic

What is the output of the following program if dynamic scoping is used?

```
void func1()
{
    int a,b;
    a=6;
    b=8;
    func2();
    a=a+b+c;
    printf(a);
}

void func2(){
    int b,c;
    b=4;
    c=a+b;
    a+=11;
    printf(c);
}

void main(){
    a=3;
    b=5;
    c=7;
    func1();
}
```

I tried applying the dynamic scoping concepts. According to that, the output is 10,32. However,  the result is 7,19. Can someone explain what is wrong with my approach?

**My Approach:-**

Initial values: a=3,b=5,c=7

In func2: 
New b,c declared. b=4. c=a+b assigns 6+4=10 to c. 
10 will be printed and a becomes 6+11=17

In func1: 
a+b+c is printed which will be 17+8+7=32.

Comment: `a` is not equal to 6 in your `func2`, it gets the global-scoped `a`.

Comment: Where did you learn that C uses dynamic scoping?

Comment: I have a pseudo code and I just implemented it using C.

Comment: At `func2` `a=3`.

Comment: And adding to `a` in func2 doesn't affect the `a` in func1. Unless this is a test, just forget about it. We never write code like this (except when trying to confuse students).

Comment: A function can access either a global variable or a local one which is shadowing it. Not some local variable of it's caller.

Comment: So, in func2 a=3,b=4,c=7 and in func1 a=6,b=8,c=7 ?? But, this is pretty much similar to static right?

Comment: I suggest you compile with `-Wshadow` and heed the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You have three sets of variable definitions:

One global `int a,b,c;`,
they will be used whenever no local variable definition overrides this.

First local `int a,b;`, inside and for `func1`;
second local  `int b,c;`, inside and for `func2`;
they will override the globals.

That is how C works and it results in this sequence:

In func1, the chronologically first executed, two local variables are intialised, but they do not have an effect on func2.

In func2 the local `b` is set to 4.
Then the local `c` is set to global `a` + local `b`, 3 + 4 == 7.
Then global `a` is increased to 17.
Output local `c` as 7.

Back in func1, local `a` is set to local `a` + local `b` + global `c`, 6 + 8 + 7 == 21.
Output local `a` as 21.

That is exactly the output you observe.

Comment: Is this approach dynamic?

Comment: I am sorry. I've implemented it using C. I'll edit it now. I didn't knew that C doesn't use dynamic scoping

Comment: If you explain what you have heard about the "dynamic scoping" I could try to apply the definition to what C does. But since you seem to have done that and the result did not match, I think the answer is obviously "No".

Comment: I heard that it takes the values from the most recent call. I have edited it now. But, still the answer is wrong according to my study material.

Comment: Would you like to quote from your study material the parts which seem to contradict? Or maybe link if it is online?

Comment: It's a multiple choice question and there is no explanation. It just says that the answer is 7,19. So, if we apply dynamic scoping is there any chance of getting 7,19?

Comment: Which language is the material referring to? And if it is C, which compiler is meant to produce that result?

Comment: If that is test, then what does the actual teaching part of the material explain about "dynamic scoping"? And for which language?

Comment: Well.. I can't really say that as it's a material for competitive examination which has the questions from all Computer science subjects. As you can already see the question itself is written in a pseudo code. So, why don't you consider the language that uses dynamic scoping and explain it accordingly?

Comment: Because you tagged C, and please do not change that. If you want to ask which languages use dynamic scoping and what their output is, or why the output you expect is theirs, then do that in a different answer.

Comment: I tried to edit that, but, it's of no use, it didn't change. Thank you I'll do that somewhere else.

Comment: "In a different question" is of course what I meant, just to be clear, but you seem to have understood anyway.

Comment: I was trying to saying that, I tried to remove that tag while editing the question a couple of minutes ago itself. But, it didn't work and now there's no question of doing it.

Comment: Hmmm. You could mean that it is not possible to delete the only tag. Once once tag has been added you can only delete it if there is another one still there. Now that you have also the dynamic tag it should be possible.